# Checkbox layout in Django manager

Tags: django, django-admin

A minor but rather annoying flaw in the default layout of forms in Django manager apps is the positioning of checkboxes where the checkbox and its label are positioned in the first column and its help text (if set) is aligned in the second column:

[image]

Either the checkbox and label should be positioned in the second column or -better- the label should be aligned in the first column (with all other labels) and the checkbox positioned in the second column.

I presume the chances are slim, but is there a relatively easy fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can do it by adding css, then it is relatively easy:

```
class MyModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media: 
        css = {
             'all': ('/path/to/css.css',)
        }
```